# Which path should I put config.toml in TiDB docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, tidb

I'm trying to integrating the [official TiDB docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/pingcap/tidb) with our appication for local development. I use docker-compose.yaml. When I run the TiDB docker container, it outputs lots of logs. It annoys me. It seems that the default log level is info according to the [doc](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/tidb-configuration-file#level). I want to set a different log level such as error, fatal to decrease log volume. Then, I think I can use config.toml and put it to somewhere in the container by coping the config file from my local pc to the container. But I'm not sure which path should I put the config.

I searched the config file with find command in the tidb container. But I couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-config` to point out the config file that you want to use.
For example,

```
version: "3"
services:
  tidb:
    image: pingcap/tidb:v6.1.0
    volumes:
    - "./tidb-config.toml:/tidb-config.toml"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    command: /tidb-server -config /tidb-config.toml
```

FYI: You can refer to these code blocks as examples.

- [tidb-action](https://github.com/Icemap/tidb-action/blob/main/entrypoint.sh#L20)
- [tidb-proxysql-integration-test](https://github.com/Icemap/tidb-proxysql-integration-test/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml#L9)

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of trouble.